# Remove product from Wishlist on second click On Woodmart

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I use Woodmart theme and I would likne to remove product from Wishlist on second click On withlist icon. Based on woodmart theme when you click on wishlist icon the product has been added to wishlist list and after that when for second time you click on the whishlist icon you can see the whishlist page and redirect to the whishlist page. So you can only abale to remove the product from the wishlist when go to the whishlis page.
In this way I wan to remove product from whishlist without sending user to whishlist page and remove product from wishlist on second click.

Any help is appreciated.
My code so far

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var clickCount = 0;
    var clickTimeout;

    $('.wd-wishlist-btn a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        var productId = $this.data('product-id');

        clickCount++;

        if (clickCount === 1) {
            clickTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                clickCount = 0;
                addToWishlist(productId);
            }, 300);
        } else if (clickCount === 2) {
            clearTimeout(clickTimeout);
            clickCount = 0;
            removeProductFromWishlist(productId);
        }
    });

    function addToWishlist(productId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: woodmart_settings.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'woodmart_add_to_wishlist',
                product_id: productId
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response) {
                    $('.wd-header-wishlist .wd-tools-count').text(response.count);
                    $('.wd-wishlist-btn a[data-product-id="' + productId + '"]').addClass('added');
                } else {
                    console.log('Something went wrong while adding the product to the wishlist.');
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error: Unable to add the product to the wishlist.');
            }
        });
    }

    function removeProductFromWishlist(productId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: woodmart_settings.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'woodmart_remove_from_wishlist',
                product_id: productId
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response) {
                    $('.wd-header-wishlist .wd-tools-count').text(response.count);
                    $('.wd-wishlist-btn a[data-product-id="' + productId + '"]').removeClass('added');
                } else {
                    console.log('Something went wrong while removing the product from the wishlist.');
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error: Unable to remove the product from  the wishlist.');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the click counter you can probably use toggleClass where on the 1st click your class gets added (say: selected) then on the 2nd click if gets removed.

So you can ignore the counter and try something like this:

```
$('.wd-wishlist-btn a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("selected"); //1st click class will be added 
        var $this = $(this);
        var productId = $this.data('product-id');
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            clickTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                addToWishlist(productId);
            }, 300);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(clickTimeout);
            removeProductFromWishlist(productId);
        }
});
```

Note sure if there's a specific reason that you are using clickTimeout. that also can be ignore if you can just rely on the "selected" class

Edited: If the above isn't working, can you try the below approach.
On first click is "selected" class getting added to the click element?

You can also try something like:

```
$('.wd-wishlist-btn a:not('selected')').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        //call add to cart function here
         console.log("product added to cart");
}

$('.wd-wishlist-btn a:selected').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
        //call remove from cart function here 
         console.log("product removed from cart");
}
```

added log lines so you can check console to see the trace if the event is getting fired.

Comment: So many thanks for your response but it does not working.

Comment: @MohsenAmra Added another approach, can you pls check.

Comment: I've check it but it does not work. Is it possible check it on your own Wordpress site with woodmart theme?